# Distance using Latitude and Longitude = NaN (in some cases)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

For two points:

```
{ lat: -6.346640110015869, lng: -39.293800354003906 }
{ lat: 66.450861, lng: 143.261551 }
```

Using popular method:

```
getDistanceBetweenPoints(location1: ILocation, location2: ILocation): number {
    const lat1: number = location1.lat,
      lng1: number = location1.lng,
      lat2: number = location2.lat,
      lng2: number = location2.lng,
      R = 6378137,
      dLat: number = this.toRadians(lat2 - lat1),
      dLong: number = this.toRadians(lng2 - lng1),
      
    const a: number =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(this.toRadians(lat1)) *
          Math.cos(this.toRadians(lat1)) *
          Math.sin(dLong / 2) *
          Math.sin(dLong / 2);

    // temp helpers
    const xx = Math.sqrt(1 - a);   ---->  a = 1.339  => sqrt(-number) = NaN
    const yy = Math.sqrt(a);
    const zz = Math.atan2(xx, yy);

    const c: number = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    const distance: number = (R * c) / 1000;
```

I found problem in debug mode:

```
a > 1
Math.sqrt(1 - a) -> sqrt(<0) = NaN
```

It means, that **a** cannot be > 1.
But how to fix that?

[map screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOeBu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work (based on the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)):

```
const RADIUS_OF_EARTH = 6378137;

const from = { lat: -6.346640110015869, lng: -39.293800354003906 };
const to = { lat: 66.450861, lng: 143.261551 };

const distance = (from, to) => {
  const latF = from.lat / 180 * Math.PI;
  const lngF = from.lng / 180 * Math.PI;
  const latT = to.lat / 180 * Math.PI;
  const lngT = to.lng / 180 * Math.PI;
  const latD = Math.abs(latF - latT);
  const lngD = Math.abs(lngF - lngT);
  const latH = Math.pow(Math.sin(latD / 2), 2);
  const lngH = Math.pow(Math.sin(lngD / 2), 2);
  const delta = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(latH + Math.cos(latF) * Math.cos(latT) * lngH));
  return RADIUS_OF_EARTH * delta;
};

console.log(distance(from, to));
```

Comment: You should also be aware of the fact, that there are always 2 possibilities to measure the distance. Especially if the points are very distant, you can reach the other point either going westwards around the globe or eastwards. Usually you are interested in the shorter of the two. If points around the international date line (+-180° longitude) are relevant for you, you should check especially if the formula also works there.